# constraint to align element to middle guideline?

Tags: xcode, storyboard, constraints

I am attempting to position two buttons in a view so that they are constrained to the middle guideline - that is, I want the space on the leading edge of Pause and the trailing edge of Skip to vary the same amount so the two buttons remain centered in the view.

I've been unable to find a way to specify the middle guideline for alignment or constraint. Sure I'm just missing something :-) The auto constraints don't do the right thing at all.

Thank you![image: Two buttons i want to align to the middle]

Answer (score 2):

Align them to center X and then set the constraint's constant to some positive or negative offset.

Comment: I ended up doing this plus a Center Y alignment on the two buttons, and equal width equal height and checking width and height also (otherwise, the buttons shrank to be just big enough to contain the text).

Thanks!